# Making infinite scroll loop into two div, synchronize scroll of these two div, and automate scroll

Tags: scroll, hover, infinite-loop, mousehover

I'm making a tricky portfolio website and have some issues as the UX/UI design is complex.

Here's the staging:
http://staging.dbd.paris/

- **Diagonal scroll**: there are two divs container that contain each a diagonal feed of images/video
- **Infinite scroll loop** : the two feeds must be infinite, so I need to make an infinite loop scrolling
- **Synchronize scroll**: I need to synchronize the scroll of the two divs as they are 'width: 100%' and 'height: 100%' to avoid z-index problem
- **Hoverable contents**: feed contents must be hoverable, even if z-index of the container is below the other container
- **Automatic and manual scroll**: the scroll must be automatic if user doesn't interact with the feed, but user can take over and scroll manually, and when he stops the automatic scroll resumes

I have some issues to loop the divs container correctly:

- **Scroll Loop**: the scrollTop is working but I don't how to have a perfect loop by setting the correct scroll positions, how can I these positions?
- **Automatic Scroll**: when the scroll reaches div's bottom, the scrollTop doesn't work to continue the auto scroll... a bug I do not understand at all :(
- **Hovering contents**: as I have to detect mouseover on a content of the lower container (z-index below the upper div), but some contents aren't hoverable on the bottom right side of the screen and I don't understand why
- **Loading problem**: sometimes when I load the page, the automatic scroll is bugging and scrolling super slow

I use only some jQuery, Vanilla Javascript and CSS for this.

There are a lot of things here and it's quite a challenge for me, so I was wondering if anyone could help me with this mission as I'm a young and lovely front-end developer...

Thank you so much!  Have a nice day!